# Solr for indexing latitude longitude or LatLng_p

Tags: solr

I was trying to import data with data import handler in solr, and my query is returning 5k of data, among them there are only 100 rows that have lat and lng. If I don't index with `<field column="LatLng" name="LatLng_p"/>` all the 5k rows are indexed by solr, however, if index with `<field column="LatLng" name="LatLng_p"/>` type pointer as lat,lng it is only indexing 100 rows. Is there a way to index 5k rows having 100 rows with lat lng value?

TIA

Comment: When you say only indexing 100 rows - what are you basing that on? Are there only 100 documents in the index afterwards, or does DIH say it only imported 100 documents? Does it say it skipped any documents? Are there any errors in the solr log about malformed coordinates? (i.e. the documents that don't have coordinates gets dropped because of the field being present, but contentless - in that case it might help to exclude empty fields).

Comment: I ran the query in sql command line, it returned all the 5k rows and so does the DIH. But it  processed only 100 rows.`Indexing completed. Added/Updated: 100 documents. Deleted 0 documents. (Duration: 23s)
Requests: 1 , Fetched: 5,023 1,083/s, Skipped: 0 , Processed: 100 13/s`. Apart from this 100 rows other do not have lat, lng. It gave a warning saying "Error creating document:" for empty pointers. I wanted to index all the documents regardless of the empty pointer with `<field column="LatLng" name="LatLng_p"/>`

Comment: Try to make your SQL-query return NULL for those columns instead of an empty string or what they're returning now; i.e. make the SQL query return a value that gets ignored by DIH.